# How to change Thumbnail size of next Gen Gallery plugin?

Tags: plugins, images

I recently installed nextgen gallery plugin . and I show my gallery with BASIC COMPACT ALBUM, but image thumb size is too small. and I want set thumbnail 300x240. I set image size with CSS but images spread and look blur, I want set thumbnail size from backend but not find any option there.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific display you will need to re-open the IGW by clicking on the preview image in the post/page then under the customizations tab change the override thumbnail size option to yes and set the dimensions as needed.

You may need to clear your image cache under Gallery > Other Options > Miscellaneous to see the effects immediately … or possible use an anonymous browser window.

Comment: can I use different thumbnail size for album

Comment: What is the "IGW"?